# Headhensive missing dropdown menu when cloning

Tags: javascript, css

I have a website which uses Headhesive, superfish and i18next. I have a header which has a navigation bar. On this navigation bar, the 2nd navItem has a drop-down menu.

The Headhensive clones the whole header but missing the drop-down menu.
This is the main menu

```
<nav id="main-menu" data-easing="easeInOutExpo" data-speed="1250">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#home">
                <div data-i18n="nav.home">Home</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#service">
                <div data-i18n="nav.services.title">Title</div>

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#service">
                            <div data-i18n="nav.services.ourservices">Our Services</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#how">
                            <div data-i18n="nav.services.howwework">How We Work</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

As you can see that the ul is the drop-down menu.

And here is the code to use Headhensive:

```
 initHeadhesive: function() {

                    if( headerEl.hasClass( 'sticky' ) ) {

                        var options = {
                            offset: 200,
                            offsetSide: 'top',
                            classes: {
                                clone:   'header-clone',
                                stick:   'header-stick',
                                unstick: 'header-unstick'
                            },

                            onInit:    function () {

                                main_menu_clone = $( '#header.header-clone #main-menu' );                                 
                                menu_trigger_clone = $( '#header.header-clone #menu-trigger' );   

                                main_menu_clone.superfish({

                                    popUpSelector   : 'ul',
                                    delay   : 250,
                                    speed   : 350
                                });

                                if( menu_trigger_clone.length > 0 ) {                  

                                    menu_trigger_clone.on( 'click', ( function() {

                                        $( this ).toggleClass( 'open' );    

                                        main_menu_clone.toggleClass( 'display-menu' );                                        

                                    }));

                                }

                                $( main_menu_clone ).find( 'ul' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {

                                    if ( $( e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() ).is( 'div' ) ) {

                                        var element = $( main_menu_clone ),
                                            divScrollToAnchor = $( e.target ).parent().attr('href'),
                                            divScrollSpeed = element.attr('data-speed'),
                                            divScrollOffset =  SPHERE.header.topScrollOffset(),
                                            divScrollEasing = element.attr('data-easing');   

                                        if( !divScrollSpeed ) { divScrollSpeed = 1250; }
                                        if( !divScrollEasing ) { divScrollEasing = 'easeInOutExpo'; }

                                        if( $( divScrollToAnchor ).length > 0 ) {

                                             element.find( 'li' ).removeClass( 'current' );
                                             element.find( 'a[href="' + divScrollToAnchor + '"]' ).parent( 'li' ).addClass( 'current' );

                                             $( 'html,body' ).stop( true ).animate({
                                                 'scrollTop': $( divScrollToAnchor ).offset().top - Number( divScrollOffset )
                                             }, Number( divScrollSpeed ), divScrollEasing );
                                        }

                                        if( windowWidth < 991  ) {

                                            menu_trigger_clone.toggleClass( 'open', false );
                                            main_menu_clone.toggleClass( 'display-menu', false );

                                        }

                                        return false;
                                    }

                                });                    

                            },                            

                        };

                        // Initialise with options
                        var stickyHeader = new Headhesive( '#header', options );

                    }
                },
```

I have seen my submenu which has "Our Services" and "How We Work" in the original header, but not in the cloned header.